# Possible to create a custom interface, making use of files managed by Alfresco?

Tags: api, configuration, interface, webdav, alfresco

Our company's switching from traditional, lame Windows shared drive to a Linux install of Alfresco.

I'm the sole developer here (...go me!) and I would like to hear any thoughts on what I envisage being an interface, created by me, accessible by my team, and drawing on files stored in Alfresco, to modify some HTML files presented by the interface.

So, I would want to make use of file locking on HTML files loaded into my interface, and also the ability to save manipulated HTML files. Offering a version history via my interface would be a nicety, given that Alfresco itself can obviously be used to retrieve that data.

I saw WebDAV support, so I thought, "Hey! I could let my designers modify my pages, given team-decided boundaries!". It sure would beat Dreamweaver for this.

I should also probably mention that yes, we do have the ability to have our soon-to-be-installed Alfresco customised for my purposes, so if it is that this *must* happen, then any advice around that appreciated also.

Thanks for your thoughts, examples and the like.

Comment: It is definitely possible to create a web application that interacts with Alfresco. I am currently exploring this ground, reading the books. One simple way of doing it is via JavaScript API: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/3.4_JavaScript_API - you can then call your scripts via URLs from external web app (can be jsp/servlets, can be PHP or even .NET)

Comment: Aaawesome, add this as an answer if you like, this is exactly what I'm after. Thanks muchly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment attached to this question is the answer I was after.